# Faild to compile tailwindcss eroor buld website

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Creating an optimized production build...

```
This error my after build website  in react js build
```

Failed to compile.

static/css/main.9a45e1a9.css from Css Minimizer plugin

```
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your file you used the forward slash ('/') character, which is an special char; if you want to use it, you could escape it with a backslash, like this: `\/`

Comment: Thanks but ...... Before this Error   =>     static/css/main.9a45e1a9.css from Css Minimizer plugin